# Waiting for return of API call and put it in a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

In the onSubmit methode I am doing a call to the getLogin methode this methodes returns a code that I need. I want to wait untill I receive the return of this method and then console log out respondseCode, but I am getting 0 as output while I should be getting a code? What am I doing wrong?

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Main title</h1>
    <form @submit="onSubmit" class="add-form">
      <div class="submit-div">
        <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="btn" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      responseCode: 0,
      responseData: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.responseCode = await this.getLogin();
      console.log(this.responseCode);
    },

    async getLogin() {
      var requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        redirect: "follow"
      };

      await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/twikey/login", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          return data.Authorization;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
    },
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either `await` or `.then()` on a promise, not both.

You can use `@submit.prevent="onSubmit"`, and remove `e.preventDefault()`

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Main title</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" class="add-form">
      <div class="submit-div">
        <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="btn" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang='ts'>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      responseCode: 0,
      responseData: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
      this.getLogin()
      .then(r => {
        this.responseCode = r;
        console.log(r)
      });
    },
    getLogin() {
      return fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/twikey/login", {
        method: "GET",
        redirect: "follow",
      })
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((r) => r.Authorization);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but I am still getting undefined when I log out responseCode after this.responseCode = await this.getLogin();

Comment: Try this:
async onSubmit() {
  this.getLogin()
  .then(r => {this.responseCode = r;
console.log(r);
});
}

Answer (score 0):

You should do your request, and

```html
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080' + this.paramId)
            .then((resp)=>{
            this.event = resp.data.data;
            console.log(resp.data.data)
})
```

in the then, the answer will get saved as event. This answer is what was returned from the backend (including if http 200). You can print it in the console, use it in the code, etc.

Also, if this event will be triggered by an object, you can have in that object a prevent. So if it is a button, for instance,

```html
<button v-on:click.prevent="doFunction();"> Sign-up </button>
```

And then have a function include this GET such as

```html
methods:{
 doFunction{
       axios.get('http://localhost:8080' + this.paramId)
            .then((resp)=>{
            this.event = resp.data.data;
            console.log(resp.data.data)
})

 }
```

Let me know if this works!!